# Having issues with google maps using sencha touch

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch but the error I am getting seems to be related to google maps api. I am making a call to google maps api to search for a a specific place in sencha touch. But I am getting below error

[image]

Here is my code inside store/Places.js file

```
Ext.define('TestIOS.store.Places', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
    model: 'TestIOS.model.Place',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCFWZSKDslql5GZR0OJlVcgoQJP1UKgZ5U',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'results'
        }
    }
}
});
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

It is due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) 
so to get the data from other servers we have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
But it seems that the latest version of the [Google Maps API (v3) does not support jsonp](http://blog.futtta.be/2010/04/09/no-more-jsonp-for-google-geocoding-webservice/). As a result, if you want to geocode, you're going to need to use the maps api:

include

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

in index.html before adding sencha microloader

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
```

and to get any address use google geocoder 
EX:

```
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': name of location },
        function(results, status) { console.log(results[0].geometry.location); });
```